# Submit Form with HTMl Service in Google Apps on leaving a field

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script

I'm creating a html form for input into a Google Spreadsheet. The form has three input fields. I need the form to execute the submit when the user tabs out of the third field. The user will be scanning a barcode and I need them to just be able to keep scanning without clicking submit. Below is the code I currently have that works other than the submit on tab.

```
<b>Receiving</b><br />

<form>
  Reference Number: <input id="location" name="reference" type="text" /> <br>
  Location: <input id="location" name="location" type="text" /> <br>
  Product SKU: <input id="sku" name="sku" type="text" /> <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input onclick="formSubmit()" type="button" value="Submit" />
  <input onclick="google.script.host.close()" type="button" value="Exit" />
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function formSubmit() {
           google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(document.forms[0]);
           this.form.elements["sku"].value = '';
           this.form.elements["sku"].focus();
       }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the onBlur tag, it runs the function when tabbing/clicking out of the element. You could also use the onchange, wich would execute the function when the bar code get scanned.

```
<input id="sku" name="sku" type="text" onblur="formSubmit()"/>
```

Comment: One more question. Now it doesn't set focus back to that field. It's clearing the field but not doing the focus.